# Interval type for Fourier Analysis on $L^2( [-\pi,\pi) ) $

Tags: analysis, fourier-series

Why is it that in many texts the natural domain of choice is $L^2 ( [- \pi, \pi) ) $ as opposed to $L^2 ( [- \pi, \pi] ) $? I would to think of the space $L^2 ( [- \pi, \pi] ) $ as the completion of $C_{c}( [- \pi, \pi] )$, so that I can use the fact that trig functions have compact support on the interval $[- \pi,\pi]$, but many books use $[- \pi, \pi)$.

Comment: Probably because you are thinking of functions with period $2\pi$ and for such functions $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$.  Why can't you just think of $L^2([-\pi,\pi))$ as the completion of $C_c([-\pi,\pi))$?

Comment: @ShawnD because the trig functions have compact support on $[-\pi, \pi]$ when restricted to that interval, and $[-\pi, \pi)$ is not compact. And in which domain do you mean we think of the functions with period $2\pi$?

Comment: I don't understand comment about support of trig functions.  Anyway, a Cauchy sequence of functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is still Cauchy when you consider restriction to $[-\pi,\pi)$.  Functions of period $2\pi$ on $\mathbb{R}$ are specified by their value on $[-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: Don't forget that $L^2$ is not a space of functions but rather consists of *classes* of functions modulo functions that are zero almost everywhere. The single point $\pi$ thus doesn't matter. If you want to think of $L^2$ as a completion you should really work on the (compact) circle *group* $S^1$ and angular measure and complete the space of continuous functions $C(S^1)$ with respect to the $L^2$ norm (the space $C(S^1)$ can be identified with the set of continuous functions $f: [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(-\pi) = f(\pi)$.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between $L^2([−\pi,\pi))$, $L^2((−\pi,\pi))$ and $L^2([−\pi,\pi])$, because a singleton is a null set. My personal preference is for the latter notation.

But when discussing continuous functions, we pay attention even to single points. The reason to use $[-\pi,\pi)$ is that this interval is in bijection with the circle $S^1$ via $x\mapsto e^{ix}$. Bringing the topology of $S^1$ to $[-\pi,\pi)$, we discover that it is just like the standard topology, with one exception: when a sequence tried to converge to the missing endpoint $\pi$, it converges to $-\pi$ instead. Having made a note of this, we can define $C([-\pi,\pi))$ as the set of functions that are continuous in this circle topology. This is a different space from the space of continuous functions on unmodified interval, $C([-\pi,\pi])$. The latter space contains $f(x)=x$ which is not in $C([-\pi,\pi))$.